# Mantener la sesion cuando descarga al capcha

Tags: python, python-3.x, session

Tengo este código que me descarga el captcha pero tengo que mandar los datos junto con la resolución del captcha. Mi pregunta es ¿Cómo hago para mantener la sesión de descarga del captcha y enviar la petición del formulario junto con la resolución del captcha (Yo me encargo de eso)?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

url = "https://demos.devexpress.com/aspxeditorsdemos/ASPxCaptcha/Features.aspx"
content = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
img = soup.find('img',id ='ContentHolder_Captcha_IMG')
print (img)
request = urllib.request.urlretrieve(urllib.request.urljoin(url, img['src']), 'captcha.jpg')
print (request)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La clave está en conservar y reusar las cookies de sesión entre peticiones. El concepto de sesión implica mantener ciertos parámetros a través de múltiples peticiones, lo que incluye mantener las cookies generadas en todas las peticiones realizadas en la misma.

Usando `urllib` de la stdlib de Python 3, tenemos el módulo  [`http.cookiejar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.cookiejar.html), que junto a `urllib.request.OpenerDirector` nos permite manejar las cookies. Hay que tener en cuenta que siempre va a ser más engorroso que si usas herramientas con mayor abstracción como `requests` (ver [Uso avanzado - Objetos de sesión](http://docs.python-requests.org/es/latest/user/advanced.html#objetos-de-sesion)) o `scrapy`.

Te dejo un pequeño ejemplo que permite autentificarse en StackOverflow, manteniendo entre peticiones la sesión, al final se hace una petición al sitio en español y se almacena el html en un fichero que puedes abrir con el navegador para ver rápidamente el resultado.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import http.cookiejar
import urllib


EMAIL = "email"
PASSWORD = "password"

BASE_URL = 'https://stackoverflow.com/'
LOGIN_URL = 'https://stackoverflow.com/users/login'
ES_BASE_URL = "https://es.stackoverflow.com/"

USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Ubuntu; X11; Linux i686; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0'
HEADERS = {'User-Agent': USER_AGENT}


cj = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)


values = {
          'email' : EMAIL,
          'password' : PASSWORD,
         }

data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values).encode("utf-8")
req = urllib.request.Request(LOGIN_URL, data, HEADERS)
with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
   html = response.read()

# Posteriores peticiones mantendran la sesión
req = urllib.request.Request(ES_BASE_URL)
with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
   html = response.read()
   with open("so_es.html", "wb") as f:
       f.write(html)
```

Si se comenta la línea `urllib.request.install_opener(opener)` se puede observar como la sesión no es mantenida entre peticiones. El ejemplo es muy básico, por ejemplo, de ser necesario se pueden almacenar las cookies en disco y ser cargadas posteriormente para ser reutilizadas.